# Inserting user information with form into database

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a form which will take in the user information and when the user clicks the submit button, it'll be saved in the **user** table in the database.

The issue is that the user input seems to not be recorded in the table and I'm not exactly sure why. Here is the outline of the form page

**add_profile.php**

```
<?php
require('Model/database.php');
$query = 'SELECT *
          FROM goal
          ORDER BY userGoalID';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$categories = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add_profile.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<main>
    <div class="fw">
        <h1 class="fw__title">Insert Your Data!</h1>

        <div class="fw__progress">
            <ul class="fw__breadcrumbs">
                <li class="fw__breadcrumbs__item">
                    <div class="fw__breadcrumbs__element">1</div>
                </li>
                <li class="fw__breadcrumbs__item">
                    <div class="fw__breadcrumbs__element">2</div>
                </li>
                <li class="fw__breadcrumbs__item">
                    <div class="fw__breadcrumbs__element"><span class="done"></span></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <form id="form" class="fw__wrapper" novalidate method="post" action="profile.php">
            <fieldset class="fw__inputs fw__step">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name*" data-label="First Name" data-validation="required"/>

                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name*" data-label="Last Name" data-validation="required"/>

                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" data-validation="required email" data-label="Email" />

                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" data-label="Phone" data-validation="phone"/>

                <div class="fw__inputs__error"><p class="fw__inputs__error--message"></p></div>

                <input class="fw__button" type="button" value="Next" onclick="next()"/>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="fw__inputs fw__step">
                <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" data-label="Age" data-validation="required naturalNumber"/>
                <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Weight" data-label="Weight" data-validation="required naturalNumber"/>
                <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height" data-label="Height" data-validation="required naturalNumber"/>

                <label for="sttype" class="fw__inputs__label fw__inputs__label--inline">Goal*</label>

                <select id="sttype" class="fw__inputs__selector" name="goal_id" data-label="Your Goal" data-validation="required select">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select one...</option>
                    <?php foreach ($categories as $goal) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $goal['userGoalID']; ?>">
                            <?php echo $goal['userGoalType']; ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>



                <div class="fw__inputs__error"><p class="fw__inputs__error--message"></p></div>

                <input class="fw__button fw__button--negative" type="button" value="Back" onclick="back()"/>
                <input id="submit" class="fw__button" type="submit" value="Review Data"/>
            </fieldset>

            <section class="fw__result fw__step">
                <h4 class="fw__result__title">Your Details</h4>

                <div id="results"></div>

                <input class="fw__button fw__result__button" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </section>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="js/add_profile.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

For all the sql commands, I have a separate page called the **profile_test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
      header('Location: login.php');
      exit;
}else{


    $user_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $weight = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'weight', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
    $height = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'height', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
    $goal_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'goal_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    $first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'first_name');
    $last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last_name');
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
    $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    //Validate INPUT_POST
    if ($goal_id == null || $goal_id == false ||
            $name == null || $age == null || $weight == null || $height == null || $first_name == null || $last_name == null || $email == null || $phone == null) {
        $error = "Invalid user data. Check all fields and try again.";
        //include('../Error/error.php');
    } else {
        require_once('Model/database.php');

        //Add user information
        $query = 'INSERT INTO user
                  (userID, userName, userAge, userWeight, userHeight, userGoalID, firstName, lastName, userEmail, userPhone)
                  values
                  (:userID ,:name, :age, :weight, :height, :goal_id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone)';

        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':userID', $_SESSION['user_id']);
        $statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
        $statement->bindValue(':age', $age);
        $statement->bindValue(':weight', $weight);
        $statement->bindValue(':height', $height);
        $statement->bindValue(':goal_id', $goal_id);
        $statement->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name);
        $statement->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name);
        $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $statement->bindValue(':phone', $phone);

        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();

        // Display the Product List page
        include('index.php');
      }
    }
?>
```

Javascript is only used for validations. Initially the user will be inserting their first set of data (first name, last name, email, phone number), then go to the second page to insert their fitness data (age, weight, height, and goal). Only after that the user can click on the submit button for the datas to be recorded in the user table.

Comment: Your form target is `profile.php`, not `profile_test.php`

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings? If not, first thing you should do is to simplify your  code to the minimum amount of code with which you can reproduce the problem. It will help you understand what is happening and what can be wrong. And, if you don't find it, it will help others help you ;)

Comment: @Nick Changed to ```profile_test.php``` but form is still not recorded in the database

Comment: @ludovico no error is shown so far

Comment: You need to add some error checking to your db routines e.g. `$statement = $db->prepare($query) or die($db->errorCode());`, `$statement->execute() or die($statement->errorCode());`

Comment: @Nick I think its the submit button. When I click it the page is not directing me anywhere, not exactly sure why. I have a separate page with a very basic design and when I click on the submit button it directs me to the index.php page

Comment: Perhaps there's something in your `add_profile.js` which is intercepting the submit and causing an error? Have you checked your console log in the developer tools?

Comment: @Nick Its weird, so I removed all the styling and only have the form in one page, there may be an issue with my ```profile_test.php```, cause its not recording my inputs.

Comment: Well I gave some suggestions for debugging that code in an earlier comment.

Comment: To make sure the form is actually delivered to your .php, you can just add this line at the very beginning of your .php file: 

<?php 
  print_r($_POST); 
  die(); 
?>

If the values are displayed, the the problem is somewhere in your .php file.
If not, then the issue is somewhere in your front-end code (html/js).

Comment: Looks like you have some issues with your validation - for starters you aren't echoing `$error` in the event one of the fields is null. After taking a quick look you don't have a field with the name "name" yet you try to filter it with `$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');` and also check it in your validation `$name == null` as this is not set it will always return null.